# Unable to Show Bootstrap modal Popup in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Content Page with the following code, which shows the Bootstrap Modal popup in Internet Explorer, but doesn't show it in Firefox. My bootstrap reference files are in Master Page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
             function openModal() {
                 $('#adverts').modal('show');
             }
</script>

 <!-- Modal Popup Ads-->
<div runat="server" class="modal fade" id="adverts" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="memberModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" clientidmode="Static" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="padding:1px; top:15%">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width:580px;">
         <div style="height:10px; margin-right:10px; margin-top:3px;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" title="Close">&times;</button>
              </div>
            <div class="modal-body" >

                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"  
                    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT id, message FROM users_html_notify WHERE (id = 1)"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Popup Ads -->
```

**VB.NET CODE BEHIND**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Pop", "openModal();", True)
End Sub
```

**Note: Above code is working fine in Internet explorer on Page load, but didn't work in Firefox**

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h

Comment: Hi Sam, the code is working fine in Internet Explorer but not working with Firefox, Also note that i'm using Bootstrap modal in Asp.net webpage Content Page..

Comment: Do you see any script errors in the Firefox web console (Ctrl+Shift+K)?